# What is the meaning of flowery language of the Vedas?

Tags: vedas

[Source](https://businesssosimple.com/2017/06/05/bhagavad-gita-mind-fixed-in-the-trance-of-self-realization-text-53-ch2-contents-of-gita-summarized/)

Sruti-vipratipanna te
Yada sthasyati niscala
Samadhav acala buddhis
Tada yogam avapsyasi
(Text 53, Ch2, Contents of Gita Summarized)

Meaning: When your mind is no longer disturbed  by the flowery language of the Vedas, and when it remains fixed in the trance of self realization, then you will have attained the divine consciousness.

Im not getting the meaning of "flowery language of the Vedas".

What is  the meaning of flowery language of the Vedas ?

Comment: Maybe a reference to how flowers unfold?

Comment: @UdayKrishna It is nice to see you back again :)

Comment: Thank you  @Rickross

Comment: Why are you reading the Gita on a 'business' website??? A legitimate source for scripture this is not. The referenced verse of the Gita is in verses 42-43, not 53. You might be better off by using an English language dictionary for understanding the English word 'flowery' or a thesaurus to find alternative words for 'flowery'.

Comment: Your question is meant to drive clicks to a business's website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the meaning of *vipratipanna* on a dictionary, like here: https://www.sanskrit-lexicon.uni-koeln.de/simple/mw/vipratipanna. "Flowery" is not the best word there, I think. The Veda is huge and some parts of it contradict each other, so it can be perplexing and uncertain. On the contrary, the verse says one should be *niścala*, https://www.sanskrit-lexicon.uni-koeln.de/simple/mw/nizcala, fixed and steady.